# Combine two SQL tables with replacement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable

Long story short, I need to be able to combine two tables (one is a continuation of the previous with a little overlap).  I then need to set one column to be a Primary Key, which means no duplicates.  When I tried to just use the Import Wizard in SQL Management Studio and import one table into the other, it just added all the data from one table into the next.  I need to figure out some way or SQL command that will import all the data from the new table into the older table, and replace any existing duplicate data with the ones from the newer table.

Think of it like this, I have two tables with the following data:

```
People_Old table
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Mary | Blue   |
| Katy | Yellow |
| Jim  | Green  |
| John | Red    |
+------+--------+

People table
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Jim  | Silver |
| John | Brown  |
| Greg | Purple |
| Liz  | Pink   |
+------+--------+
```

Assuming the "Name" column are suppose to be a Primary Key, I would like to add the data from the newer "People" table into the older "People_Old" table, but replace the overlapping data so there are no duplicates.  In this example, I would like the final "People_Old" table to be:

```
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Mary | Blue   |
| Katy | Yellow |
| Jim  | Silver |
| John | Brown  |
| Greg | Purple |
| Liz  | Pink   |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: For a bit more info,

Comment: You could add the primary key first, then "insert-select" the datas from the table that contains the newer data, then "insert ignore-select" the datas from the older table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: A merge query might work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` statement, something like:

```
replace into people_old select * from people;
```

Comment: Another way is [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS old;

CREATE TABLE old
(Name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Color  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO old VALUES
('Mary','Blue'),
('Katy','Yellow'),
('Jim','Green'),
('John','Red');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new;

CREATE TABLE new
(Name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,Color  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO new VALUES
('Jim' ,'Silver'),
('John','Brown'),
('Greg','Purple'),
('Liz' ,'Pink');


SELECT * FROM old;
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Mary | Blue   |
| Katy | Yellow |
| Jim  | Green  |
| John | Red    |
+------+--------+

SELECT * FROM new;
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Jim  | Silver |
| John | Brown  |
| Greg | Purple |
| Liz  | Pink   |
+------+--------+

INSERT INTO old 
SELECT name
     , color 
  FROM new 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE old.color = new.color;

SELECT * FROM old;
+------+--------+
| Name | Color  |
+------+--------+
| Mary | Blue   |
| Katy | Yellow |
| Jim  | Silver |
| John | Brown  |
| Greg | Purple |
| Liz  | Pink   |
+------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```